# xamarin android

Tags: xamarin

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста с передачей данных(TextView,EditText,Button) из Activity в Fragment и обратно?

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается? Опишите подробнее в тексте вопроса.